Unison fails with "Cannot find canonical name" when used with profile
I use Unison to sync folder between MacOS and external SSD drive connected via usb. External drive has ExFAT file system.
If I execute Unison by specifying two roots, then it works fine.
unison /Users/user.name/Nextcloud /Volumes/ssd_sync/macbook/nextcloud -fat=true

But when I execute Unison using profile, then it fails with an error
❯ unison nextcloud
Unison 2.53.7 (ocaml 5.2.0): Contacting server...

Error: Cannot find canonical name of "/Volumes/ssd_sync/macbook/nextcloud": unable to cd either to it ("/Volumes/ssd_sync/macbook/nextcloud": No such file or directory)
or to its parent "/Volumes/ssd_sync/macbook
("/Volumes/ssd_sync/macbook: No such file or directory)

My profile contains exactly the same root folders and looks like this
❯ cat /Users/user.name/Library/Application\ Support/Unison/nextcloud.prf
root = "/Users/user.name/Nextcloud"
root = "/Volumes/ssd_sync/macbook/nextcloud"
fat = true

I can cd to "/Volumes/ssd_sync/macbook/nextcloud". I noticed that error message has only on opening quotation mark ("/Volumes/ssd_sync/macbook: No such file or directory). Could you be related? If yes what could be the reason for this?
My main question is how to make Unison work for my case using a profile?
Update 1
I also tried with a different ocaml version by without any success.
unison version 2.53.7 (ocaml 4.14.2)

I see that people are voting to close this question. I guess because it's about specific tool and not about any programming language. What stack exchange site should I use instead to ask such question about unison tool? Also it's confusing that stackoverflow has unison tag, but shouldn't be used to ask questions about unison.

The problem is with the quotation marks, they aren't valid paths. In the command line it works because the parameters are interpreted a bit different than reading them from the file. Change config to:
root = /Users/user.name/Nextcloud
root = /Volumes/ssd_sync/macbook/nextcloud
fat = true

